# Paste text from UserForm textbox to corresponding cell to ActiveCell on another Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get activecell address and then use it to input text from userform textbox on another Sheet in the same Workbook. I have tried to get it working with code below but it is not working.

So I have tried to `Set acad = ActiveCell.Address` and use it in `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(acad).Value = "hello"`

Here is my solution:

```
Private Sub CommandButton25_Click()

Dim r As Range
Dim acad As Range

On Error GoTo noval

Set r = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)

Set acad = ActiveCell.Address

If Intersect(r, ActiveCell) Is Nothing Then GoTo noval

ActiveCell.Validation.Delete

With ActiveCell.Validation
 .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly
 .InputTitle = Me.TextBox1.Value
 .InputMessage = Me.TextBox2.Value
 End With

 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(acad).Value = "hello"

 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

Exit Sub

noval:

With ActiveCell.Validation
 .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly
 .InputTitle = Me.TextBox1.Value
 .InputMessage = Me.TextBox2.Value
 End With

 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

On Error GoTo 0

'ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "   " & ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Your assignment (`Set acad = ...`) is from a string to an object, which probably gives you a 424 error Object Required, because `Address` returns a string, not a Range object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment (`Set acad = ...`) is from a string to an object, which probably gives you a 424 error Object Required, because `Address` returns a string, not a Range object.

You'd probably then need to do: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(acad.Address).Value = "hello"`

```
Private Sub CommandButton25_Click()
Dim r As Range
Dim acad As Range

Set r = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
Set acad = ActiveCell

With acad.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly
    .InputTitle = Me.TextBox1.Value
    .InputMessage = Me.TextBox2.Value
End With
acad.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(acad.Address).Value = "hello"

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice edit! Now I don't receive any error but also there is no "hello" in B17 on Worksheet "Data" for some reason. I select B17 from my current sheet. So word hello should popup to corresponding cell on sheet "Data".

Comment: Assuming `ThisWorkbook` *is* the active workbook at runtime. That may not be the case. Up to you to debug :)  You may step through the code and see what occurs on that line?

Comment: Problem seems to be in `If Not Intersect(r, acad) Is Nothing Then` where "Not" should be removed.

Comment: @user7202022 yes that seems correct. But I'm also not sure why that `Intersect` statement is logically necessary to begin with. I think you can safely remove it and this way the code will always put the value in the `acad` (ActiveCell).